# Flash Bulb battery depletion

Tags: batteries, watts, charge, discharge, capacity

Extremely simple question for you. Probably beneath all of you to answer apologies for that. My camera's flash is rated in Watt seconds.  My battery is rated in mAh .

If my battery can output 1000 milliamp hours and outputs at 110 Volts. And my camera flash draws 100 Watt seconds per fire. Assuming there are no other variables and it's a perfect system, how many camera flashes could I fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1000\mathrm{\ mA \cdot h}\times110\mathrm{\ V} = 396\mathrm{\ kJ}$$

$$100\frac{\mathrm{\ W \cdot s}}{\text{flash}} = 100\frac{\mathrm{\ J}}{\text{flash}}$$

$$\frac{396\mathrm{\ kJ}}{100\frac{\mathrm{\ J}}{\text{flash}}} = 3960\text{ flashes}$$

Comment: 396/100=3.96 but you have it at 3960? I can definitely fire the flash more then 3.96 so I'm still confused.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: 396kJ or 396,000J

Comment: @user2875251  The *k* in *kJ* stands for "kilo", and "kilo" is an [SI prefix](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html) for factor of 1000x multiplier.  Now, here's an extra credit question:  what does *m* in *mAh* stand for?

Comment: Milli.  Thanks for the response.  I get it now.  Forgot all my conversion factors.